# Error while trying to Run my HTML code in Firebug

Tags: javascript, html

```
Need Help.
```

Getting Syntax error from Firebug,
    when I click "Run".
    "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'       /*EXPR...Page Title
        
        
        .....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's caused by a fundamental misunderstanding of how developer tools work.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't JavaScript code. In order to "run" this code, you need to create an `html` page. Create a file and name it `index.html`. Give it the contents of your post. Then you can open this file (by double clicking on it) and you'll see the contents of this page in your default browser.

If you'd like to run `JavaScript` you can create a `.js` file. You can then reference it inside of the `index.html`'s body by using a`<script>` tag.

It would be a good idea for you to go through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web) to get a deeper understanding of how it all works.